# email delivery report in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to know whether the email is delivered to the respective email account or not Using Firebase Auth API's

Let me know if there is any workaround ?

Comment: How is `firebase-realtime-database` related to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to the Firebase Authentication. The user is retrieved from mAuth.getCurrentUser() method, and the sendEmailVerification() method is called on it. This gets Firebase to send the mail, if the task was successful, you'll see that a toast will pop up showing that it happened.

```
sendEmailVerification()
```